# Compiling application only source available

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to compile some code that I found for an Application that I want to use. 
Now I've download VB.NET express created a new project and just replaced the code with the one I got, but this isn't creating the forms (textfields etc.) at all, so I can't compile it.
Is this normal ? What else do I have to do to be able to compile it.

This is the source code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim psc As String
    Dim pwchange As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Not My.Settings.pw_save = "" Then
            TextBox6.Text = My.Settings.pw_save
            CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        End If
        If Not My.Settings.new_pw_save = "" Then
            TextBox7.Text = My.Settings.new_pw_save
            CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:verifyCaptcha").InnerText = TextBox5.Text


        'Die 1. - 5. Zahlenkombi
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:rn1").InnerText = TextBox1.Text
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:rn2").InnerText = TextBox2.Text
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:rn3").InnerText = TextBox3.Text
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:rn4").InnerText = TextBox4.Text

        'Button bestätigen
        'WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")

        'Passwort Eingabe
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:passField").InnerText = TextBox6.Text
        'WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:next").InvokeMember("submit")
        'Abfrage ob richtige Captcha Eingabe
        'WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:next").SetAttribute("value", "Free")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainPagePart:next").Focus()
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")

        psc = 1
        'Dim wert As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("j_id66")
        'MessageBox.Show(wert.InnerText)

    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(50, 342)
        If psc = 1 Then
            'Dim wert As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("j_id66")
            ' Dim wert As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint()
            'MessageBox.Show(wert.InnerText)
            Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(150, 310)
            psc = 0
            If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Bei deinem PIN-Code und/oder Passwort ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte &uuml;berpr&uuml;fe die korrekte Eingabe des PIN-Codes oder Passworts.") Then
                Label1.Text = "Pin oder Passwort Falsch"
                psc = 0
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(100, 370)
                'WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://customer.cc.at.paysafecard.com/psccustomer/GetWelcomePanelServlet?&language=de&javax.faces.ViewState=j_id1")
            ElseIf WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Bei der Eingabe des PIN-Codes oder Passworts ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte korrigiere deine Eingabe. Hast du ein Passwort für diese paysafecard vergeben, kontaktiere bitte unser Service-Team.") Then
                Label1.Text = "Pin oder Passwort Falsch"
                psc = 0
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(100, 370)
                'Abfrage ob richtige Pin-Code Eingabe
            ElseIf WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Bitte korrigiere deine Eingabe") Then
                Label1.Text = "Pin oder Passwort Falsch"
                psc = 0
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(100, 370)
            ElseIf WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Der eingegebene Text stimmt nicht mit dem Angezeigten überein.") Then
                Label1.Text = "Captcha falsch"
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red
                psc = 0
                Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(120, 350)
                'WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://customer.cc.at.paysafecard.com/psccustomer/GetWelcomePanelServlet?&language=de&javax.faces.ViewState=j_id1")
            ElseIf WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Verf&uuml;gbares Guthaben") Then
                Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green
                Label1.Text = "PSC OK"
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tabForm:password").Focus()
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("passwordPage:passwordOld") And Not pwchange = 1 Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordPage:passwordOld").InnerText = TextBox6.Text
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordPage:password1").InnerText = TextBox7.Text
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordPage:password2").InnerText = TextBox7.Text
            pwchange = 1
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordPage:submit").Focus()
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
            Label5.Text = "Das neue Passwort lautet:" & TextBox7.Text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tabForm:close").Focus()
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        Label5.Text = ""
        Label1.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox8_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox8.TextChanged
        If TextBox8.TextLength = 16 Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox8.Text.Substring(0, 4)
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox8.Text.Substring(4, 4)
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox8.Text.Substring(8, 4)
            TextBox4.Text = TextBox8.Text.Substring(12, 4)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            My.Settings.new_pw_save = TextBox7.Text
        Else
            My.Settings.new_pw_save = ""
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox2.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
            My.Settings.pw_save = TextBox6.Text
        Else
            My.Settings.pw_save = ""
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at the code you need to have a form that goes with the code to provide the UI for the application. If you design your own remember to use the events dialog and wire up each event that you need.

Comment: is there any easy way to do this ? I have absolutely no idea about vb.net I've just download Visual Basic express to compile it, as i thought that was all i had to do.

Comment: Nope, you don't have everything you need to compile it.